# DB2: accessing the column by column number

Tags: sql, db2

Can I select the columns by column number like for example

```
select custome.0, customer.1 from customer
```

table customer with id and name as columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you are asking for, but if you are willing to pay for a round trip you may be able to use this query to find the column name to column number mapping:

```
SELECT COLNAME, COLNO, TYPENAME, NULLS FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS 
       WHERE TABSCHEMA = ? and TABNAME = ? order by colno
```

(from Perl's DBI::DB2)